# ag-Grid <> Selenium : Getting Grid Data

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am trying to get the ag-GRID data using Selenium.

I was reading ag-GRID documentation and it suggests following to get the grid data:

```
it('first row should have expected grid data', () => {
    element.all(by.css('div[row="0"] div.ag-cell-value'))
        .map(function (cell) {
            return cell.getText();
        })
        .then(function (cellValues) {
            expect(cellValues).toEqual(["Toyota", "Celica", "35000"]);
        });
});
```

However, when I test following on Chrome console - it does not return any records/elements :

```
$$("div[row='0'] div.ag-cell-value")
```